# Benefits of 64GB+ of ram, partly regarding superfetch

Tags: memory, ssd, ramdisk, superfetch

I already have a very fast computer with a SSD, a 700 series GPU, and a Intel Xeon. That said I am considering upgrading my RAM to 64GiB (from 16GiB), possibly more.

1. Im wondering if windows 8/10/superfetch is smart enough to load my entire os and/or applications folder (Assuming it fits), and if it is id like to personally test the difference this makes (vs 16GiB).
2. If I do upgrade the RAM, will it matter if I add differently specced RAM? (Also if not will it matter if the ram is of different size (eg two 8GiBs and two slower but larger DIMMs).

Comment: Purely anecdotally [& I'm also on a different OS] but empirically, 64GB RAM really only becomes useful when you have massive tasks - though better than just 16GB which I'd consider borderline these days. Just doing 'regular stuff' on a day to day basis & only rebooting this machine for OS updates, I tick along nicely at about 20-25GB RAM usage, swap untouched, 0 bytes.

Comment: If you really want to ramp the speed, consider more Xeons & possibly RAIDing SSDs, or get them on the PCIe bus rather than SATA.

Comment: You might also want to list which Xeon. Xeon is a very generic indicator from the hyper modern down to decades old slow single core P4's.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if windows 7/8/10/superfetch is smart enough to load my
>   entire os and/or applications folder (assuming it fits),

I doubt it does this.  You could manually trigger something though. E.g. copy all the files to NIL/NUL. I assume that this will fill the disk cache with the relevant data.

But if you reallly want more IO speed, consider mirroring or striping SSDs.

> and if it is is like to personally test the difference this makes
>   (vs 16gb).

As long as you do not reboot windows (and any modern OS) will slowly start using free memory as disk buffers. So if you start a program the first time it might not be faster, but starting it a second time should see a speed gain.

(All assuming that you do not run out of free memory, which would cause disk buffers to be flushed).

> If i do upgrade the ram, will it matter if I tack on different RAM to
>   my current RAM.

No. It is fine to populate with different sizes, though if you mix then you might loose speed from dual channel access.

Examples:

```
One 2 GiB     Standard start  

One 4 GiB     Same with more memory  

Two 2 GiB     Faster than 1x4GiB if your memory controller supports
              has dual channnel. (average 5% speed gain).

 Two 2 GiB    ... of different speeds. Speed will slow down to the
                  slowest comon values...

Two 2 GiB and one 4 GiB .... This gets interesting and depends on chipset.
              In theorie the memory controllen can use dual channel mode
              on the first two and single on the second.

Two 2 GiB and two 4 GiB  ... dual channel mode on both. As far as I know
              always at the slowest shared speed. This is not a hard 
              requirement and a smart chipset could use different speeds
              for both channels.
```

(Adjust where needed for triple and quad channel. Those are not common in end-user land, but neither are Xeons.)

Not asked but otentially helpful: RAMdisks. Either for tmp folders or persistent ones which get their data filled after booting and whose contents can be copied on shutdown.

Also not asked but as a practical point: Measure. What is the slowest point? Simply adding more memory will not help [much] if it is not the bottleneck. And more memory can even slow you down due to less cache hits.

Comment: and then there's the 64gb hibernate file on the disk...

Comment: Yup. Assuming you use hibernate.  Personally I would just shut down the computer and boot a fresh install in the morning. That also helps to keep things nice and fast.

Comment: There are also these limits to be considered ==> http://www.ricksdailytips.com/windows-memory-limits/

Comment: With a Xeon build I was assuming a 64 bit install. But you are right, it should be mentioned explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Since Windows 8, the [superfetch service detects your drive type and in case for a SSD, it stops prefetching data](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Disabling-Hibernation-Superfetch-onboard-VGA#time=05m50s), because that give no benefit. Instead of stopping the service completely superfetch only ignores SSDs but leaves the functionality turned on for normal HDDs.